# Compiling Windows Workflow files with .xaml extension

Tags: .net, windows, xaml, workflow-foundation-4

We have written a few Windows Workflow files in Visual Studio (with .xaml file extension). We wish to be able to build assemblies from the command line. We tried the [wfc.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms734733%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) compiler but it expects the files to be in the .xoml format which appears to be outdated to the .xaml format. Any help on how to build .xaml files into assemblies would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The WFC.EXE tool is a Wf3 artifact and not related to WF4. Using WF4 all you need to do is add the XAML file to a VS2012, or VS2010, solution and set the Custom Tool in property sheet to **MSBuild:Compile** and the Build Action to XamlAppDef. After that just recompile the project and you have an assembly with embedded workflows.

Depending on your need that might not even be needed though. The ActivityXamlServices will let you load a XAML file and execute the workflow without compiling it. See [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/03/07/loading-xaml-workflows-in-wf4.aspx) for more details.